# Unreachable 'yield' still strangely affects function

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, yield, control-flow

If you run the following snippet, it will ignore the 'print' on line 2 and 'exit' on line 3.  However, if you comment out the *already unreachable* 'yield' from line 4, lines 2 and 3 will execute normally.

This makes me think that Python (3.5.2) looks for a 'yield' anywhere in the function, and if one is found, even an unreachable one, nothing is executed until a next() is called on the returned iterator.  Up until now, I was under the impression that the function would execute normally up until hitting a yield, at which point it would begin acting like an iterator.

```
def func():
    print("> Why doesn't this line print?")
    exit() # Within this function, nothing should matter after this point.  The program should exit
    yield "> The exit line above will exit ONLY if you comment out this line."


x = func()
print(x)
```

Does this seem strange to anyone else?  Does anybody have some insight to share here?

Comment: No. Generators and normal functions are different beasts from the moment of compilation.

Comment: The mere presence of a `yield` statement turns a function into a generator. Note the bolded text in the linked question/answer: "When you call the function, the code you have written in the function body does not run".

Comment: Consider, `def g(): print('foo'); yield 1`. If you do `x = g()` *you won't see anything printed*.

Comment: "I was under the impression that the function would execute normally up until hitting a yield, at which point it would begin acting like an iterator." Any function with a yield will return a generator when called. When you subsequently **start that generator**, it will run until hitting a yield.

Comment: By calling a function that contains a ``yield`` statement, you are creating a generator. That is why the content don't get executed unless you call ``next`` on it. But without the ``yield`` it would be a normal function that executes those lines once you call it.

Answer (score 1):

When a function has a yield, even if it is not reachable, it will be a generator.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is the `yield` statement. When you use `yield` inside a function, it will create a generator. Keep in mind that any function with a `yield` will return a generator when called.

**Try this:**

```
def func():
    print("> Why doesn't this line print?")
    exit()

x = func()
print(x)
```

**Results:**

```
Why doesn't this line print?
None
```

And then the program exits.